# import database phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been given an export of a database but when ever i import i get an error that i believe is because foreign keys exist in the database

```
SQL query:

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--
--
-- Constraints for table `instance`
--
ALTER TABLE  `instance` ADD CONSTRAINT  `instance_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (  `user_id` ) REFERENCES  `user` (  `id` ) ,
ADD CONSTRAINT  `instance_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (  `cat_id` ) REFERENCES  `category` (  `cat_id` ) ;


MySQL said: 

#1005 - Can't create table 'dalejc.#sql-152c_243' (errno: 150)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading it into a fresh database. If it doesn't work, then you need to get the missing SQL. If it does, then you'll have to go through the file and pull out the parts you're missing.

Comment: if the guy is going to export it again, is there anything he can do do avoid this error

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like one of your `KEY` fields does not match.

In particular, check for `UNSIGNED`ness of integer fields, whose defaults may vary across installations.

<sup>Inspiration: google search for [mysql errno 150](http://forums.devarticles.com/mysql-development-50/mysql-foreign-key-problem-errno-150t-7704.html)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is probably right. Try getting a detailed error message as suggested at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

> Similarly, if an ALTER TABLE fails and
>   it refers to error 150, that means a
>   foreign key definition would be
>   incorrectly formed for the altered
>   table. You can use SHOW ENGINE INNODB
>   STATUS to display a detailed
>   explanation of the most recent InnoDB
>   foreign key error in the server.