# Copy the mysql database folder to new computer (windows)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i copied a database folder (the folder name is the db name) from other computer to a new computer, actually the database folder is accidently erased by a uninstall program, i recovered that by a harddisk recovery tool,  but when i open the phpmyadmin, all forms of this database can't be loaded in mysql, is there any chances to get it work?

thanks

**Update**

replaced the old ibdata1 file, all table are loaded

Comment: Was the database server already installed on the machine? Is it running? `all forms of this database can't be loaded in mysql` is not an error message - what is reported in phpmyadmin? What is reported in the mysql logs?

Answer (score 0):

upload all the database again, 
also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859545/import-database-phpmyadmin) and `Related` questions on right bottom of this page..